# How to get the scroll position of a kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I am trying to gather the scrollLeft/scrollTop position data from my kendo grid. So far i have this:

```
var mainGrid = $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var testgrid = $("#mainGrid div.k-grid-content");
topoffset = testgrid.offset();

//which gives me these numbers but they do not look correct...
//left  44.959999084472656  Number
//top   174.55999755859375  Number
```

Then I want to demonstrate auto-positioning by forcing my grid to scroll to top: 0 and left: 0. Then back to the position I captured with this...

```
//send to top
testgrid.scrollTop(0);
testgrid.scrollLeft(0);
```

> Grid doesn't scroll to top as expected.

```
//send to previous position
testgrid.scrollTop(topScroll);
testgrid.scrollLeft(leftScroll);
```

> Grid doesn't scroll back to previous position.

It just doesn't seem like your allowed to force scroll to a position in kendo grid.

Comment: i just did it in developer tools, did you want to stay on the page and do it or is it like you click a button and get the position of the scrollbars currently and then go back to that position

Comment: well the main problem is that after i refresh the grid. kendo automatically goes to scrollTop(0) and scrollLeft(0). So I'm trying to send it back to the record that was edited. its a real pain. I don't even know why kendo does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you need to have this in your databound event. So if you want to have it set previously you can do:

```
databound: function(e){
  $('.k-grid-content').scrollTop('150');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.k-grid-content').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.k-grid-content').animate({
            scrollTop: 200
        }, 1000);
    }, 5000);
});
```

And just switch out the values to what you want in speed an distance for the scroll ( I just used scrollTop but you can use variations ). If you want to play with the grid first and then capture where it is just use:

Then use a sessionStorage variable to save it and then enter it in your databound event. To capture the position of the grid before refresh you can do:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(){
   $('.k-grid-content').scrollTop(); // capture how far from top
   $('.k-grid-content').scrollLeft(); // capture how far from left
});
```

This doesn't need to be in your databound event.

Comment: can you supply a Dojo? or Fiddle?

Comment: i thought this could help my original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920023/kendo-grid-jumps-to-top-after-onsave. but all it does is after it refreshes it goes to top of the grid, then back to the saved row. Kendo is super clunky!

Comment: it's the answer to my question but its not the solution to my overall problem. Because im using scrollable: { virtual: true } .k-grid-content doesn't exist. I can move the grid by using .k-virtual-scrollable-wrap. but it saves incorrect left and right positioning. Also when i gather the Left and Top it still goes to the top of the grid then goes to the coordinates i gathered in a delay jumpy motion. i just dont get why the grid has to alway go to top after every save. I appreciate you help @Keith

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to get the scroll position of a Kendo grid:

```
$('html, body').animate({
 scrollTop: $("#unSubmittedGrid").offset().top-300
}, 'slow');
```