# Kendo Grid jumps to top after onSave

Tags: javascript, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a grid that i need to set:

```
scrollable: {
    virtual: true
},
```

When users edit a cell then updates (or onSave(e)) their changes. The grid resets back to the top of the page. I don't know why. Users lose their place every time they try to change a cells contents.

When i make

```
scrollable: false,
```

it stays put. I think this is a huge bug in Telerik Kendo. Has anyone figured out how to stay in place on the grid after saving changes?

**UPDATE**

This problem only occurs in IE 11. Unfortunately my client can only use IE11.

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler (the function that gets executed when you click save)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to save your current location before you bind.

in

```
onGridBinding(){
    _currentLeftPosition = $(".k-virtual-scrollable-wrap").scrollLeft();
}

in onGridBound(){
    //Go Back to previous position
    var vs = mainGrid.wrapper.find('.k-grid-content').data('kendoVirtualScrollable');
    var scrollGridContentOffsetTop = mainGrid.wrapper.find('.k-grid-content').offset().top;
    var selectContentOffsetTop = mainGrid.content.offset().top;
    var distanceTop = selectContentOffsetTop - scrollGridContentOffsetTop;
    var scrollTop = vs.verticalScrollbar.scrollTop();
    $("#mainGrid div.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap").animate({scrollTop: distanceTop + scrollTop,scrollLeft: _currentLeftPosition}, 0);
    $("#mainGrid div.k-scrollbar-vertical").animate({scrollTop: distanceTop + scrollTop}, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for you:

Use `GridViewRowInfo` to get row info of selected row and set scroll to your custom row and column.

```
if (this.radGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
{
    GridViewRowInfo row = this.radGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowInfo;
    radGridView1.TableElement.ScrollTo(row.Index, 0);
}
```